# SSRS Multi-Category Formatting for Column Chart

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to visually link column chart categories so that a user doesn't have to guess what is included in a given group, just by the position of the category label. But I don't even know what to search for to get the formatting I'm after. I've grabbed a screenshot from the web. That red arrow is pointing to the formatting I am searching for. Anyone out there know what it's called or how to achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The red arrow indicates another level of Category Grouping.

They are a higher level grouping than the Monthee group. The A and B may refer to Quarters that the Months fall in.

You would add a second grouping to the charts Category Groups by clicking on the Plus sign next to Category Groups of the chart.

[image]

The Property to show the Grouping lines is the Major Tick Marks on the Horizontal Axis' Properties.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer, but maybe I phrased my question incorrectly. So I already have multiple categories, that's easy enough, but I can't seem to get the lines that visually link the higher level categories together. So in the screenshot in the question,  the category group "A" has a nice line that runs the length of its grouping, then bumps up agains category "B", which has its own line.

Comment: @KirstieBallance Ah - I added a pic for that property. It's not very intuitive.

Comment: OMG! thanks so much. That is exactly what I needed.